# weak referenced Delegates becomes nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, standards

I'm creating a delegate with weak reference and need to go through the couple of completions(closures) then `delegate` becomes nil. When I remove the `weak` reference it works fine.

```
weak var contentDelegate: ContentDelegate?
```

Actually is it allow to create a delegate property without `weak` reference in swift best practices? What are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually is it allow to create a delegate property without weak
>   reference in swift best practices? What are the drawbacks?

Yes you can create delegates without `weak` reference .

No it's not under best practices scope .

Drawbacks, are mainly the risk of having a retain cycle where references are not getting released from memory, leading to a memory leak .

Comment: However if you're not creating any cycles and pretty much sure of it, you can get it away with it, its fine

Answer (score 1):

would be great if you can share your code.
Without code hard to say, but looks like you have async calls, and on some async call `delegate`, I suppose it's controller or maybe some service, released from the memory

if you remove `weak` you will get retain cycle, when `delegate` and owner of this delegating are holding each other in the memory

Comment: Actually it is really complex to share a code here. However I'll check about your mentioned points. Thanks.